# Using numpy where functions

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand the behavior of the following piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
theta = np.arange(0,1.1,0.1)
prior_theta = 0.7
prior_prob = np.where(theta == prior_theta)
print(prior_prob)
```

[image]

However if I explicitly give the datatype the where function works as per expectation

```
import numpy as np
theta = np.arange(0,1.1,0.1,dtype = np.float32)
prior_theta = 0.7
prior_prob = np.where(theta == prior_theta)
print(prior_prob)
```

[image]

This seems like a data type comparison. Any idea on this will be very helpful.

Comment: The key test is `theta == prior_theta`.  Look at that by itself.  `np.where/nonzero` just finds the indices where that is `True`.  Read the `np.nonzero` docs with care.

Answer (score 3):

This is just how floating point numbers work.  You can't rely on exact comparisons.  The number `0.7` cannot be represented in binary -- it is an infinitely repeating fraction.  `arange` has to compute 0.1+0.1+0.1+0.1 etc,, and the round-off errors accumulate.  The 7th value is not exactly the same as the literal value `0.7`.  The rounding is different for float32s, so you happened to get lucky.

You need to get in the habit of using "close enough" comparisons, like `where(np.abs(theta-prior_theta) < 0.0001)`.

Answer (score 0):

`np.isclose` (and `np.allclose`) is useful when making floats tests.

```
In [240]: theta = np.arange(0,1.1,0.1)
In [241]: theta
Out[241]: array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. ])
In [242]: theta == 0.7
Out[242]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False])
```

`np.arange` warns us about using float increments - read the `warnings` section.

```
In [243]: theta.tolist()
Out[243]: 
[0.0,
 0.1,
 0.2,
 0.30000000000000004,
 0.4,
 0.5,
 0.6000000000000001,
 0.7000000000000001,
 0.8,
 0.9,
 1.0]
In [244]: np.isclose(theta, 0.7)
Out[244]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,
       False, False])
In [245]: np.nonzero(np.isclose(theta, 0.7))
Out[245]: (array([7]),)
```

`arange` suggests using `np.linspace`, but that's more to address the end point issue, which you've already handled with `1.1` value.  The 0.7 value is still the same.